# Was Senator Pat Geary set up by the Corleone family?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-godfather-2

According to the discussion regarding a typical deal between Michael Corleone and Sen. Pat Geary, in *The Godfather: Part II*, Michael refuses to pay anything extra to the senator, after which later in the movie Sen. Geary is found in a not so good condition with his mistress in one of the motels under Fredo’s (Michael’s elder brother) colleagues to which Tom is seen taking a glare of the situation. But the mystery is still unsolved...

**Was the Sen. set up by The Don?**
**If yes, then why?**
**Was it all coincidences?**

Well, the answers could be the same for all of the above questions, or they may *not*. Anybody with any idea?

Links to:

[Discussion between the two](https://youtu.be/Re9O7kDtt6c)

[Sen Pat is screwed](https://youtu.be/im3vHOEm-r4)

Comment: @Napoleon- Thanks for the edits. But its a mystery indeed;)

Comment: Do you remember near the beginning of the movie when Pat Geary was trying to shake down Michael Corleone (for lack of a better word)?  Geary was acting like an arrogant jerk.  Michael wouldn't budge to his demands.  I always thought that was why Geary was set up.  Corleone could totally control him now, even at the Senate hearings later in the movie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Was the Sen. set up by The Don?

## Yes

Coppola confirms this is the case in the DVD commentary saying that

> "That's how lethal the Corleone's were that they would send a guy like Neri to hurt a woman like that and kill her just to get this political figure in their pocket".

In the movie itself it's just **heavily** implied that this was a Corleone set-up.

Notwithstanding that Geary just *happens* to kill a prostitute in a Corleone-run brothel and has no memory of the incident there is a telling by-play in the middle of the scene.

While Geary is protesting his lack of memory and *"it was just a game"*, we see Al Neri, a Corleone hitman/enforcer washing his hands in the rooms bathroom.

Hagen gives a head nod to Neri to indicate that Neri should make himself scarce.

[image]

You can see the whole scene on Youtube

The [original script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Godfather-Part-II.html) does not contain this scene. Instead the Corleones set up Geary by paying off $30,000 of fake gambling markers Geary is supposed to have signed.

This would have the appearance of Geary accepting a bribe so setting up Geary seems to be a consistent plot point.

Geary is an influential Senator and was serving on a  U.S. Senate committee investigating organized crime.....having him in your pocket would be a definite plus.

Comment: A video link, wherein Coppola admits this, would be very useful. Thanks.

Comment: There is no video link...it's in the DVD Commentary as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

The scene in question implies that Senator Geary was drugged by someone at the brothel.  When he woke up, he was in the middle of a crime scene controlled by the Corleone's.  This was how they were able to get a political favor (the gambling license) out of an otherwise unwilling politician.

Comment: Thanks- Ya he was indeed drugged, but, was it all the set up by the Corleones or was it just a “lucky” coincidence, according to my question?